# Python Regular Expression named groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

Im trying to build a regular expression that captures any number (integer, float, with scientific notation or not). Im using groups so that if I need to update something I update only one line. Here's what I'm doing:

```
intNumber = r"(?P<Integer>-?(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*))" # Integer
floatNumber = r"(?P<Float>"+intNumber+r"\.[0-9]+)" # Float
sciNumber = r"(?P<Scientific>"+floatNumber+r"(e|E)(-|\+)?[0-9]+)" # Scientific
anyNumber = r"(?P<AnyNumber>"+sciNumber+"|(?P=Integer)|(?P=Float))" # Any number
```

The problem is that although each of the regex works on its own, when I combine them all in `anyNumber` using or (`|`) it captures only scientific notation numbers and not the rest. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** To refine my question, is it possible to have a dynamically generated regex (with the goal of simple single spot maintenance in mind) that also is flexible enough to allow me to use its components separately, without problems like redefinition of groups and with convenient naming of the groups? I know I may be asking too much..

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/fu9eOy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(?P=Integer)` is a named *backreference* that matches the *same text* (not recurses the group subpattern!) as  matched by the capturing group named "Integer". Same is with `(?P=Float)`. That means, you need to use the pattern itself, not the backreferences.

Also, you cannot use the named backreferences if you plan to build the regex dynamically that way. Use non-capturing groups and your pattern building will look similar to

```
import re
intNumber = r"-?(?:0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)" # Integer
floatNumber = intNumber+r"\.[0-9]+" # Float
sciNumber = floatNumber+r"[eE][-+]?[0-9]+" # Scientific
anyNumber = r"{0}|{1}|{2}".format(sciNumber,floatNumber,intNumber) # Any number
print(re.findall(anyNumber, '12 12.34 12.34E-34'))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/fu9eOy)

Comment: Ok thank you! But if I also want to refer to intNumber group Integer, or group Float, because I'll use them separately as well (and not just for making the anyNumber regex) then I'll need to have capturing groups. In that case it would be great if I could have named capturing groups. 

See my question edit :)

Comment: You just cannot use two named groups with the same names in `re` regex. With the `anyNumber` just defined with your patterns as `r"{0}|{1}|{2}".format(sciNumber,floatNumber,intNumber)`, you will get an exception. You may consider using PyPi regex module, or forget about such deep level naming.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
intNumber_re = r"(?P<Integer>-?(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*))" # Integer
floatNumber_re = r"(?P<Float>"+intNumber_re+r"\.[0-9]+)" # Float
sciNumber_re = r"(?P<Scientific>"+floatNumber_re+r"[eE][-\+]?[0-9]+)" # Scientific
groupNames_re = r'(\?P<Integer>)|(\?P<Float>)|(\?P<Scientific>)'
anyNumber_re = r"(?P<AnyNumber>{0}|{1}|{2})".format(re.sub(groupNames_re,'?:',sciNumber_re),
               re.sub(groupNames_re,'?:',floatNumber_re),re.sub(groupNames_re,'?:',intNumber_re)) # Any number
```

Effectively I'm removing the group names (regex for those is in `groupNames_re`) when I construct the `anyNumber` RE with the `re.sub()` functions. It is a bit ugly but it works and gives me the flexibility that I want. Thanks Wiktor for your input, I ended up using a bit of your code :)